# Need Advice to fix this issue

Tags: addtocart

[![I want to add "ADD TO CART" button to my all the product can any one suggest me I would like to put a "ADD TO CART" button to every product I have. Could someone please advise me on how to do this? I'm a new user and not very experienced with Magento. ] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cokkG.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cokkG.png)

---

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want to add *Add to Cart* button with all the products so my customers can add without to open the product.

Comment: In magento default theme already we are having "Add To Cart" button If a product is enabled and the quantity is more than 1, the "Add to Cart button" will appear on the PLP and PDP pages. Do you want this customization in any other specific theme or conditions?

Answer (score 0):

@Easy Shelf, The screenshot you have shared shows that you have some third-party theme or a custom theme integrated. kindly check the **list.phtml** file of the active theme you will see the code for the add to cart button functionality and if you're not a developer message me personally I will guide you :)